# Conditional 3 table Join

Tags: mysql, sql

Table 1

```
PropertyId

1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Table 2

```
PropertyID PropertyCode PropList ID

1            2            45
3            4            67
5            6            89
```

Table 3

```
PropertyID IType

1           3     
2           3     
3          11    
4          11    
5           3
6           3
```

Target Table

```
PropertyID   PropertyCode

1             45
2             45
3             67
4             67
5             89
6             89
```

Step 1: Join Table 1 and Table 3

Step 2: If `Table 1.PropertyId.Itype = 3` Then Join Table 1 and Table 3 on `Table1.PropertyID = Table2.PropertyId`

Else

Step 3: If `Table 1.PropertyId.Itype = 11` Then Join Table 1 and Table 3 on `Table1.PropertyID = Table2.PropListId`

Sorry for Reposting but wanted to post the problem correctly.

I would really appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried something already? Also, is this sql-server or mysql?

Comment: I tried this in the start considetring on table 1 and table 3   SELECT t1.*,
        t2.PropertyCode
FROM  Test.dbo.DailyBudgetExtract T1 
  INNER JOIN Test.dbo.DailyPropertylListExtract T2 ON T1.PropertyID = T2.ProplistID

Comment: Then Join Table 1 and Table 3 on Table1.PropertyID = Table2.PropListId. Did you mean, table 1 and table 2 here?

Comment: @Lesya Yes, my bad I meant table 1 and table 2 only.

Comment: `Table 1.PropertyId.Itype` table1 does not have itype right?

Comment: @SATSON you are right only table 3 has it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, something like this:

```
;
WITH    joinedt1
          AS ( SELECT   a.PropertyId AS PropertyId ,
                        b.IType AS IType
               FROM     tab1 a
                        LEFT JOIN tab3 b ON a.PropertyId = b.PropertyID
             )
    SELECT  A1.PropertyId ,
            C.PropList_ID
    FROM    joinedt1 A1
            INNER JOIN TABLE2 C ON A1.PropertyId = C.PropertyId
    WHERE   A1.IType = 3
    UNION
    SELECT  A2.PropertyId ,
            D.PropList_ID
    FROM    joinedt1 A2
            INNER JOIN TABLE2 D ON A2.PropertyId = D.PropListId
    WHERE   A2.IType = 11
```

Comment: Hey Lesya, I would really appreciate if you could format this. Kinda difficult for me to understand.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by formatting. The code is formatted by the sql redactor

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation and column definitions don't match, could you please correct them?

Multiple IF...THEN usually translate into CASE, this could be what you want:

```
FROM T1 
JOIN T3 
  ON T1.PropertyID = T3.PropertyID
JOIN T2
  ON T1.PropertyID = 
     CASE T3.Itype 
        WHEN  3 THEN T2.PropertyId
        WHEN 11 THEN T2.PropListId
     END
```